# unbound sessionScoped ManagedBean value

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean, session-scope

I have a SessionScoped ManagedBean. 
I want to reset all value of this bean. I'm using JSF 2.1.0-b03

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
}
```

Now, I've the method, which resets all value to null. But I don't like this solution.

```
private void unboundValue() {
    name= null;
}
```

**How can I unbound value from SessionScoped ManagedBean?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual reset seems the proper way. If you want to invalidate the whole session, not just one bean, then call `session.invalidate()`. If it's just one bean, the manual field reset is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could remove the *SessionScoped* managedbean from the *ExternalContext*'s sessionmap. The next time the bean get's accessed a new one will be created with default values, or you just create a new bean and insert it into the session map and therefore replace the *old* one.
Of course the procedure is a little overhead, but if you have lots of values which needs to get resettet, that could be one solution.

Otherwise you would need some kind of *reset/unboundValue()* method like you stated already.